# Mysql fast insert, slow delete, wrong index

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have an event that generates some data representing `accumulators` in what I call a `transaction`. It proved to run a lot faster generating the accumulator from scratch than to try and match them up to existing ones. Therefore I have given them a `transaction_id`, create them and then in one query then delete the previous transactions.

Creation of approx. 2 million rows in the table needs about 40 seconds, however deletion currently takes about 20-30 minutes using the query below.

```
DELETE
  FROM accumulator
WHERE id_acca_set = @set_id
  AND ( transaction_id != @transaction_id or transaction_id is null);
```

Looking at the innodb status I see the following when the query is executing. As far as I can figure out there seems to be no conflicting lock at this stage.

```
---TRANSACTION 11535589892, ACTIVE 259 sec updating or deleting, thread declared inside InnoDB 4657
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
29009 lock struct(s), heap size 3776720, 1195753 row lock(s), undo log entries 1195753
MySQL thread id 108262, OS thread handle 131874376460032, query id 9689717638 event_scheduler updating
```

The `accumulator` table is defined per below. I noticed that it is not using `IDX_accumulator5` but `IDX_accumulator3` which does not include the `transaction_id` instead.

```
CREATE TABLE acca.accumulator (
id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_acca_set int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
id_event bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
id_back_outcome bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
id_lay_outcome bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
acca_id varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
prev_acca_id varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
leg_number int(11) NOT NULL,
score double DEFAULT NULL,
transaction_id varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
INDEX IDX_accumulator (id_acca_set, acca_id, transaction_id),
INDEX IDX_accumulator2 (id_acca_set, leg_number, acca_id, transaction_id),
INDEX IDX_accumulator3 (id_acca_set, id_event, id_back_outcome, id_lay_outcome, leg_number),
INDEX IDX_accumulator4 (id_acca_set, prev_acca_id, id_event),
INDEX IDX_accumulator5 (id_acca_set, transaction_id),
INDEX IDX_accumulator6 (transaction_id, id_acca_set, leg_number, score)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 242051170
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 282
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;
```

I am running MySQL 5.7.13 on CentOS 7. I do not use an swap memory and have about 10GB remaining free memory, 6GB are allocated to the INNODB Buffer. InnoDB settings in `my.cnf` are:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 6
innodb_commit_concurrency = 4
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_thread_sleep_delay = 100
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout = 10
```

Comment: You are telling that you need delete 2.000.000 of rows .. ?

Comment: Title reads like a poem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any DBMS which will use an index to resolve a negated predicate ( transaction_id != @transaction_id).

I don't understand why you are adding the new records *then* deleting the old ones. If you do it the other way around (truncate the table) then it'll take a tiny amount of time. If you want to make sure you have data to fall back on, then an alternative approach would be to rename the existing table then create a new one (with the original name) to hold the new data.

Comment: I considered truncating the table and doing exactly what you suggest, but I have multiple acca sets and cannot just rename the table completely. Also once I have generated a new set, I need to switch another calculation to use the new transaction_id which for various reasons I cannot do in one transaction.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to create a view of a union of the old data tabbles (which makes sense at performance would suck) you could use a state attribute (which could be driven off a trigger)

Comment: I ended up with another table where I log all the transactions and their status. I now use that to delete expired transactions and can pinpoint matching records with an `= @transaction_id` rather than the negation.